# How to random access avro records in python?

Tags: python, avro

I have a set of index/avro file (kb/gb), I use the following program to read it

```
import avro.schema
from avro.datafile import DataFileReader
from avro.io import DatumReader, DatumWriter

schema = avro.schema.Parse(open(r"hmd.avsc", "rb").read())
reader = DataFileReader(open(r"data", "rb"), DatumReader())
reader_index = DataFileReader(open(r"index", "rb"), DatumReader())
```

The problem is the reader is very slow, when data is as large as 5gb, it takes around 1 hour to iterate every line into memory, then I want to use multi-thread to speed up the process, the idea is to read the index which is small, and as I have the keys in my hand, I can divide them into 10 parts, then I can speed up the process by doing it concurrently, so is there any python api that can support random access with avro reader?

Edit1:

I do see there is a seek method at 1.2 api version, https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/api/py/avro.io.html, but it seems that it's gone at 1.8.2, is there any other alternative?

Comment: You might want to look at the fastavro library. Otherwise, pyspark should be able to read the file and parallelize it

Answer (score 1):

I will talk from the java point of view, but I would guess the python side have the same. did you try the [seek](http://avro.apache.org/docs/current/api/java/org/apache/avro/file/DataFileReader.html#seek-long-) method in the DataFileReader object?  it allows random access to the file and speed up your process, the complex problem will be point to the correct sync point. I would recommend save the sync point during the writing of the files.

UPDATE: The link has been changed to point to the most recent docs.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, I do see there is a seek method in avro 1.2 api, but at 1.8.2 package, the DataFileReader doesn't have it any more, any other advice?

Comment: The link in the answer has been updated to the most recent docs; the seek method is still available.